# joining 2 tables without duplicates

Tags: mysql, sql, delphi

I  am trying to join an old sql table with a new one but exclude the duplicate entries, this needs to be in a delphi program as well, and im a noob at that, any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

These both keywords will make your data to combine and display in a single column.

- **Union** - Removes the duplicate entries of the table
- **Union All** - Includes the duplicate entries

It would be better if you provide an example with input and output, that would clarify your question the most.

Comment: Answers to a questions which is not clear is not appropriate. Better give a comment than an answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `union all` operator instead of the `union` operator for joining two tables that not remove duplicates from the table.